# VSCode doesnt like when I create a function as a constructor variable

Tags: javascript, angular, function, typescript

I am using Typescript for my application to create some classes.  I noticed though, I am trying to define a function variable which would be a callback of sorts.

```
class GridButton {
    constructor(public text: string, public icon: string, public clickEvent: function){ }
}
```

I was hoping that this could be a thing, it seems that the code analyzer doesn't like it.

I was planning to expand upon this by creating a AngularComponent for this as well, but I could just have it as a passed in function: `@Input() clickEvent;` for example:

```
<grid-button [clickEvent]='testFunc'></grid-button>
```

But I didnt want to just assume the idea of having this as a NG Component but instead a standalone class which I need to handle and accomplish some tests for.

Is there a way to pass in a Callback Function etc into a Class Constructor without NG Though?

Comment: `function` is a keyword in JavaScript. Maybe you meant `Function`? Either way you'd be better off explicitly specifying the parameter types and return type like `clickEvent: (event: MouseEvent) => void` or something like that.

Comment: To add more comments beside Patrick's, what you are trying to do feels like an antipattern. Angular has `Output` which is great for catching some events. 99% of the time, you should not need to pass a function to catch some event. Angular offers better ways to communicate between two components. Can you explain your case little bit further?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I am trying to not couple things to angular as much as pass in a self contained event as a part of the constructor.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you might be right.  I know `function` is a keyword, but i wasnt sure what the proper type was for what I was looking for.  Maybe it is in fact `Function` . Thank you!